# Convert a string into Date

Tags: c#, date, date-formatting

I have a string containing information `08/23/2016~08:00 - 12:00~D` . I want to first convert it into date i.e `08/23/2016` and then convert this into `Tuesday,August 23,2016` . Is it possible to convert it in this format?

Comment: So you're not interested in the time info?

Comment: @stuartd No. only the date

Comment: In that case, just strip the date out (ie up to the first tilde) and then it's easy to parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of [`string`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx)- and [`DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h21f14e(v=vs.110).aspx)-methods

```
string input = "08/23/2016~08:00 - 12:00~D";
string datePart = input.Split('~')[0].Trim();
DateTime dt;
if (DateTime.TryParse(datePart, DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    string output = dt.ToString("dddd,MMMM dd,yyyy", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
}
```

[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the simple solution and providing the link for information on Date and Time Formatting. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
string inp = "08/23/2016~08:00 - 12:00~D";
string str = inp.Split('-')[0].Trim();
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "MM/dd/yyyy~hh:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string s1 = date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
string s2 = date.ToString("dddd,MMMM dd,yyyy");
```